# How do I navigate up to a parent activity not on the back stack?

Tags: android

I'm trying to navigate up to a parent activity. If the parent activity is at the top of the back stack, it works. If the parent activity is not on the back stack, navigating up using NavUtils simply goes back to the previous activity.

My app's minimum SDK is 16.

Manifest snippet:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.ParentActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
<activity
        android:name=".activities.ChildActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_child"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.ParentActivity">
```

Code snippet for ChildActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(this, ParentActivity.class);
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, intent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I have tried a few different ways of implementing up navigation but none have solved this problem. Changing ParentActivity's launch mode to "standard" does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

`NavUtils.navigateUpTo(Intent)` does not create a parent activity if it's not on the stack. Your minimum API is 16 so you can call stack navigation methods directly without using support classes.

In you case you should call [`onNavigateUp()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNavigateUp()) method. If you want to customize up-navigation you can also override [`shouldUpRecreateTask(Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#shouldUpRecreateTask(android.content.Intent)) and [`onPrepareNavigateUpTaskStack(TaskStackBuilder)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareNavigateUpTaskStack(android.app.TaskStackBuilder)). If the `shouldUpRecreateTask(Intent)` returns `true`, the parent activity will be created if it doesn't exist on the stack.